# Trying to combine awk and zcat with multiple filtering criteria

Tags: unix, awk, zcat, .gz

I have very large file (40m x 400 columns).

Structure like:

```
chr  pos  snp
1   1   rs500
2   4   rs501
2   6   rs502
17   6   rs503
```

Given a name myfile.gz

To search 3rd column for a given value the following works:

```
zcat myfile | grep rs500$
```

However, to search for two criteria - say `chr = 17` and `pos = 6` I was trying to do the following, but can't get it to return values.

```
zcat myfile | awk '{ if ($1 == 17 && $2 == 6) print }'
```

No error, but no return of anything.
I've done this kind of filtering in the past when the file wasn't .gz compressed with no issue.

such as this command in a much larger different file that filters two columns on criteria and then retrieves the results.

```
"awk '{ if (NR == 1 || ($39  >= 0.03 && $36 <= 1e-04)) print }' myfile.notgzcompressed"
```

But I can't seem to combine that syntax with the need for zcat, because I don't want to have to unzip my huge archive

```
EDIT to add information based on comments
zcat myfile.gz | head -2 | od -c
0000000   c   h   r  \t   p   o   s  \t   r   e   f  \t   a   l   t  \t
0000020   c   h   r   _   h   g   1   9  \t   p   o   s   _   h   g   1
0000040   9  \t   r   e   f   _   h   g   1   9  \t   a   l   t   _   h
0000060   g   1   9  \t   V   E   P   _   e   n   s   e   m   b   l   _
0000100   s   u   m   m   a   r   y  \t   r   s   _   d   b   S   N   P
0000120   1   5   1  \n   1  \t   1   0   1   8   0  \t   T  \t   C  \t
0000140   1  \t   1   0   1   8   0  \t   T  \t   C  \t   W   A   S   H
0000160   7   P   (   1   )   :   d   o   w   n   s   t   r   e   a   m
0000200   _   g   e   n   e   _   v   a   r   i   a   n   t   (   1   )
0000220   |   D   D   X   1   1   L   1   (   2   )   :   u   p   s   t
0000240   r   e   a   m   _   g   e   n   e   _   v   a   r   i   a   n
0000260   t   (   2   )  \t   r   s   2   0   1   6   9   4   9   0   1
0000300  \n
```

For more info, I am using R and fread() to pass commands like this so that unix does the parsing prior to loading into the R environment. This chr and pos lookup have been assigned.

```
fread(cmd = paste0("zcat ", myfile, " | awk ","'{ if ($1  == ", chr ," && $2 == ",pos,") print }'")) -> h2
```

Comment: Do you need to specify the delimiter? I.e. does `zcat myfile.gz | awk -F"\t" '$1 == 17 && $2 == 6' | head` return ten lines matching your criteria?

Comment: fwiw, I cut-n-pasted the 5 lines of data into a file named `myfile`, ran `gzip myfile`, then ran your first `zcat | awk` script and received a single line of output: `17   6   rs503`; I'm wondering if there may be some odd characters in the file ... if you run `zcat myfile | od -c`, do you see anything other than spaces, the visible characters and `\n`? (if you're not sure what to look for then cut-n-paste the entire `od -c` output into the question)

Comment: I am thinking you have an issue with how the lines are bing auto split by awk. Your example works fine for me. But if your delimiter were wrong, then the `$` variables are not set correctly. You might check if you have DOS line endings in your file?

Comment: try something like `zcat myfile | grep rs500$ | head -1 | od -c` to check your columns are whitespace-delimited

Comment: if I convert your sample back to original form and gzip it, changing the awk to search for `$1==1 && $2==10180` works fine. I don't think `awk` is your problem.

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly nothing to do with `zcat file | awk` (please tell us for sure if it works for you on the command line or not) but instead about how you call that pipeline from `R` within `fread(cmd = paste0(,,,))`. Maybe the wrong quotes or unescaped quotes or quotes in the wrong places or unescaped `$`s or something, idk. Simplify your command to try to figure it out and then if you still can't ask a question tagged with `R`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that whilst using

```
zcat myfile | awk '{ if ($1 == 17 && $2 == 6) print }'
```

with humongous `myfile` problem might arise at `|`. Namely `|` has limited machine-dependant capacity (further reading [The Pipe Buffer Capacity in Linux](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/pipe-buffer-capacity)), if your `awk` does not read quickly enough `|` might become jammed with data.

If your data has never leading zeros and has field separated by single TAB character and you are interesting in 1st field being equal to value and 2nd field being equal to value then you might use GNU `grep` for that task, 1st field holding `17` and 2nd field holding `6` might be expressed following way, let say you have `command` which produces TAB-separated output

```
chr pos snp
1   1   rs500
2   4   rs501
2   6   rs502
17  6   rs503
17  600 rs504
```

then

```
command | grep -P --color=never '^17\t6\b'
```

gives output

```
17  6   rs503
```

Explanation: I instruct GNU grep to use perl-flavor regular expression and do not contaminate output with escape sequences and look for lines starting with (`^`) `17` followed by TAB character, followed by `6` spanning to word boundary (`\b`) - in order to prevent grabbing lines where 2nd column starts with `6` but is not `6` (observe last line of `command` output).

*(tested in GNU grep 3.7)*

Comment: I don't think that's how pipes work. consider: `seq 100000000 | ( sleep 30; wc -l)`

Comment: @jhnc this is possible, certainly I am not pipe ninja, but then why user is getting described behavior?

Comment: Both of the standalone and R versions of the sample code provided work fine with the sample data provided, so I would expect the explanation to be either (a) the actual data doesn't match what the actual program expects; or (b) the actual program being run doesn't perform the intended operations.